# RabbitMQ HTTP API request 401 Unauthorized

Tags: api, rest, rabbitmq, unauthorized

I'm trying to access to RabbitMQ rest, but I got 401 unauthorized error. I want to access to queue information and to get messages number.

I found this as a solution

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("xx.xx.xx.xx", 15672, "http");

HttpPut request = new HttpPut(
    "/api/queues/%2F/queue-name");

httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("guest", "guest"));

AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);
BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

StringEntity input = new StringEntity(
    "{\"vhost\":\"/\",\"durable\":\"false\",\"auto_delete\":\"false\",\"arguments\":{}}");

request.setEntity(input);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, request, localcontext);
```

but it doesn't work. I saw that DefaultHttpClient class is depreciated so I tried something like this

```
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("xx.xx.xx.xx", 15672, "http");
    HttpPut request = new HttpPut("/api/whoami");

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("guest","guest")
    );

    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider);
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);

    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, request, context);
```

and then to access to REST thought WebTarget, something like this

```
WebTarget queueREST = RESTClientManager.getClient().target("xx.xx.xx.xx:15672/api/queues/%2F/queue-name");
```

but I still get error 401 Unauthorized. Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

"guest" user can only connect via localhost. To allow remote connections using guest change `rabbitmq.config` and add `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].`

[source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html]

In my case, I fix it with:

```
sudo sed -i 's/{default_pass, <<"guest">>}$/{default_pass, <<"guest">>},\n    {loopback_users, []}/' /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using this https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop .

Answer (score 0):

You could use too [my rabbitmq-management-java-client](https://github.com/nithril/rabbitmq-management-java-client)
 library which is more complete.

For example a snippet to authenticate and list queues:

```
RabbitManagementApi api = RabbitManagementApi.newInstance("http://localhost:15672/" , "user" , "password");
List<Queue> queues = api.listQueues("vhost");
```