# Why does my URL to get RabbitMQ bindings work in a browser but not with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

If I put this URL in a browser, the list of my RabbitMQ bindings is displayed:

http://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:6004/api/bindings

However, I get a 401 (unauthorized) if I use that same URL with `HttpClient`:

```
private void RemoveOldBindings(IModel channel, string exchangeName)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string url = "http://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:6004/api/bindings";

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        // remaining code here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // We always hit this exception block with a 401 error
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

My RMQ log file shows that the user was authenticated, but apparently not authorized? Why?

$ docker logs fff8766052a2 | tail -10
2021-06-24 17:54:12.326 [info] <0.8127.0> connection <0.8127.0> (172.18.0.1:52312 -> 172.18.0.2:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

There is a comment, here, that the guest user can only connect to localhost:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37281517/279516

So I tried replacing 127.0.0.1 in the URL with localhost, but still get a 401.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to set the auth header instead of just relying on including it in the URL.

```
private void RemoveOldBindings(IModel channel, string exchangeName)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Notice the credentials are gone from the URL
    string url = "http://localhost:6004/api/bindings";

    try
    {
        // This was the fix
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"guest:guest")));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        // remaining code here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```